# Composite C1 - How to have multiple editable areas in a master layout

Tags: c1-cms

I have a MasterLayout.cshtml (same as in example site).

As I understand it there can only be one area where page templates can insert content?

However - I would like the main content area to be editable - and a footer area, to be editable on every page - without having to duplicate the structure of the end of the main area and the start of the footer on every page template.

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can move repeating parts of the template to page template features, editable in the Layout perspective.

http://docs.composite.net/Layout/Page-Template-Features

The editable parts of the content on a page can be defined as content placeholders in a template.

http://docs.composite.net/Layout/Razor-Page-Templates/Adding-Placeholders

Comment: I thought about this. The problem is (should have mentioned) - the MasterLayout is shared between multiple sites - and the footer must be different on each site.